# Can $f$ ever has uncountable number of Local maxima or minima?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This question suddenly came to my mind (May be very silly question...)

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$ and twice differentiable. Can $f$ ever has uncountable number of Local maxima or minima? (Twice differentiablity can be ignored for finitely many points).

I was thinking of counter-example (obviously), but could not find one.(I am really really bad at finding counter-example actually!)

I thought about the example $x^2\sin\Big(\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)$ when $x\neq 0$, and $0$, when $x=0$, but this function is not twice differentiable everywhere.

**Added:**

Note: Twice differentiablity can be ignored for finitely many points (Because I think if I impose this condition the problem will be interesting...)

Comment: And has *countably many* extrema.

Comment: Your question nearly amounts to asking if a once differentiable function can have uncountably many roots. (But constant zero sections mut be ruled out.)

Comment: well yes... that's right!!! @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Arthur: that function is defined by an algorithmic procedure, from a function with countable extrema. I'd be surprised it leads to uncountabiity.

Comment: Note that this is not possible in $\mathbb C$, since a complex valued function with uncountably many zeroes must be identically zero by a version of the identity theorem. But that doesn't mean it isn't possible in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @wythagoras how to prove that, any link may be..

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334557/entire-function-with-uncountably-many-zeros

Comment: why can't you pick  a function so that it is constant in an interval and then fix the corner points to have differentiability?

Comment: Also [Countability of local maxima on continuous real-valued functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27907/countability-of-local-maxima-on-continuous-real-valued-functions)

Comment: If a local extremum is strict, it is required to be unique in an open interval around it. That open set has positive width and so there can only be countably many in a unit interval, and thus on the real line.