# Functional Equation with uncountably infinite solutions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

Is it necessarily true that a functional equation of analytic functions that is true at uncountably infinitely many values is always true?
Ex. $$f(x)*g(x) = h(x) $$ for analytic functions $f,g,h$ is true for $1<\Re(x)<2$. Is it necessarily true for all $x$? If so, is there a specific theorem explaining why or stating so?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: Essentially answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334557/42969